# Проблема с подключением к бд JDBC : Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе с помощью jdbc, но получаю исключение.Хотя в Mysql workbench все работает, запросы обрабатываются, да и в самой intellij idea при нажатии на test connection никаких проблем. Но при запуске main() - ошибка. Вот сам код:

```
    import com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.Driver;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection connection;

        try {
            Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            if(!connection.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("connected");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2326)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at database.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2999)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)
    ... 13 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте старый и простой способ:

```
    try{
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
        String username="root";
        String password="password";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        try(Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password)){

            System.out.println("Connection to Store DB succesfull!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Connection failed...");

        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вот что выводит в консоль 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at database.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Connection failed...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: я добавил  `ex.printStackTrace();` в catch

Comment: @Artem я поправил ответ, проверьте

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка - `Connection failed...

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.`